# Manual or jumper settings for mainboard PWA-286C

Tags: identify-this-computer, 80286

I have an old mainboard, type PWA-286C, running a 10 MHz Intel 80286. I have no manuals, so I am looking for documentation on it.

I am especially wondering if there is a connector for the real time clock battery. Maybe J21? Also what the voltage for it might be. Also wondering about the large J17 near the CPU.

Additional question: The board is running a Phoenix 3.0 BIOS. I guess there is no internal setup program? Can I use GSETUP on this?

Here is a picture:

[image: PWA-286C]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RTC on your motherboard is the Hitachi HD146818P DIP chip located SouthEast of the CPU in your photo. According to [the datasheet](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/115060/HITACHI/HD146818P.html) it uses a backup battery voltage that is nominally 3VDC. I suspect that J21 is *probably* the battery jack, but I don't see any indication of polarity.

J17 is a 34-pin connection that is likely for the built-in Floppy Disk Controller (FDC). Use it to connect two standard PC floppy drives.

Comment: Concerning the floppy controller: That's neat. Will make booting it simpler. I just ordered a USB drive floppy emulator, since I don't have any drives or floppies anymore. 
Concerning the RTC: Do you think it makes sense to probe the pins of J21 and the IC with a multimeter to see what is connected to which pin? Using the datasheet of the HD146818P as a guide.

Comment: J17 looks like a 3-pin header. So if you can find the correct PC battery replacement it should only connect one way. But it is definitely a good idea to confirm which pin is GND/Vss with a multimeter too.